# arviz.plot_ppc: "posterior predictive mean"

Tags: pymc3, arviz

[image]
[image]

Hello!

After running a model for a simple linear regression model in pymc3, I'm trying to do a plot.
As you can see both plots show the "posterior predictive mean score", but I was wondering whether can I plot this distribution around the "posterior predictive mean score" (not around "observed score"), in arviz, similar to what is shown in the first figure?

Both figures were made using the same data:

```
Score <- c(78.93,58.2,67.47,37.47,45.65,32.92,29.97)
Drugs <- c(1.17,2.97,3.26,4.69,5.83,6,6.41)
```

---

**EDIT:**
Bayesplot with bounds:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the question? If I understand correctly the [legend of the top plot](https://mc-stan.org/bayesplot/reference/PPC-distributions.html#arguments), y corresponds to observed score and y_rep to posterior predictive score. posterior predictive mean score is not present. It can be removed by using `az.plot_ppc(..., mean=False)`

Comment: Assuming you are using the data for both plots (which is what I suspect), the differences you see are due to the differences in the KDE algorithms. As only the 7 values present in `Score` are available, inferring the whole pdf is complicated. ArviZ's approach tries to keep the observed boundaries, therefore the KDE is only defined between the minimum and maximum values in the array of observed values, then normalized. If this boundaries are not enforced (as it looks like bayesplot does) then the KDE is defined outside said boundaries

Comment: When taking these boundary effects into account (which also affects the normalization of the pdf), both plots seem to show the same result

Comment: @OriolAbril, how do I remove the boundaries in `arviz.plot_ppc`, if possible. I cannot see a way in the documentation https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/generated/arviz.plot_ppc.html#arviz.plot_ppc. It is easy to add these limits in bayesplot with `Trim=T`.

Comment: It is currently not possible because we believe it to be a bad practice that should not be encouraged. Trying to guess the pdf outside the range of the observed data gives plenty of problems in many situations. That being said, pdf inferred with kde methods having only 7 values is generally not to be trusted. If using ArviZ, I'd recommend using `plot_ppc(..., kind="scatter")`. I think this does not answer your question though :/, I hope it was somewhat informative at least